# Cognos frame work manager: format numeric column to show currency dynamically

Tags: cognos

In this url, it is shown how you can format a particular column to according to particular currency. 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/caapps/v10r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_fm.10.1.0.doc%2Fug_fm_id13919format_SAP_query_items.html

Now in a result set, there may be 2 rows and each may be of a different currency and also different number of decimals. According to the method here, it seems that we need to hard code the currency and the number of decimals on the entire column. Is there a way to set it dynamically?

I have two columns in the result set, one is the amount the other one is the currency. Based on currency, i want to format  the amount column. From db, the amount column just comes back as a number.
How can I do it?

Comment: That link is takling about using locale to define format. Locale is a session level parameter (i.e. basically the user). You won't be able to use that method to do row level formatting. For example if Joe logs in and he is Japanese, ALL of the figures will use Japanese formatting. You'll need to use the method I have mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think how this would be done in Framework Manager. You can do it in Report Studio however.

He are some high level instructions on how to do it in Report Studio:

1. In Condition Explorer, create a variable which results in a different string for each currency. For example if your currency code field is [Table].[CurrencyCode] and it has things like 'AUD','CAD' etc. in it then your variable expression would just be the field:

   [Table].[CurrencyCode]

   This will simply output the currency as its result
2. Still in the variable creation screen, add values the the 'Value' window to for each possible currency code result
3. Go to the report page, click on the field that contains your actual currency value (i.e. 13.50 and set it's Style Variable property to the variable that you just created
4. Now go back to condition explorer and select your first currency
5. Ensure your currency value field is selected and edit the 'Data Format' field to the appropriate format
6. Repeat 4 & 5 for each currency

Here is another guide to how to do this:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21339405

This is called 'Conditional Formatting' if you would like to research it further.

Unfortunately this solution needs to be done at the report level and can't be done down at the the FM level. I'm not aware of a way that you can conditionally set the data format in FM like this.

Comment: Excellent response sir. Thank you very much.